# Vim: sort command's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, vim

Does anyone know which algorithm is used internally on Vim when `:sort` command is used?
Is the same algorithm used to sort 10 lines than the one used to sort 10000 lines?

Comment: The src-code is [here](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/) feel free to browse it :-)

Comment: This is not documented. Did you take a look at [the source code](http://www.vim.org/download.php)?

Comment: _Why_ are you asking? Is this just general interest, or have you encountered exceptionally slow sorting in Vim?

Comment: I have not encountered nothing weird. Is just general interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim is open source; why don't you just have a look yourself? It's easiest via the online Mercurial repository:

http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/ex_cmds.c

Vim delegates the actual sorting to the `qsort()` library function.

Answer (score 0):

When available, an external `sort` program is used. The internal algorithm is undocumented.

***edit***

Well, "undocumented as in "`:help :sort` doesn't explain how the internal algo works".